# Creating my own "BBB image" for installing it in several BBBs?

Tags: system-installation, hardware, disk-image

I have been working with a Beaglebone Black for a while now, I have created a software for a device which I am happy with. Now I have a few more Beaglebone Blacks where I would like to install the same configuration, libraries and also my software, without going through all the libraries and software installation process over and over again, one by one. I wanted to know if there is a way to create an image (or even some kind of "distro") of my original Beaglebone Black, and install it in the others (from the USB or the SD card, whatever is the best way).